# Listing most commented news

Tags: asp-classic

I have two tables in my database.

- Comments

  - CommentsID
  - MembersID
  - CommentsBy
  - CommentsDesc
  - CommentsActive
  - CommentsDateEntered
  - NewsID
- News

  - NewsID
  - MembersID
  - CategoriesID
  - ImagesID
  - NewsTitle
  - NewsShortDesc
  - NewsDesc
  - NewsActive

I need to take top 5 commented news (active comments and active news) and list their titles using one query. I hope I made sense. But I am really confused here. Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT TOP(5) News.* 
FROM News 
WHERE News.NewsActive = 1 
ORDER BY 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM Comments 
     WHERE Comments.NewsId = News.NewsId AND Comments.CommentsActive = 1) DESC;
```

Response to your comment would be something like:

```
SELECT TOP(5) News.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM Comments 
     WHERE Comments.NewsId = News.NewsId AND Comments.CommentsActive = 1) AS TotalComments
FROM News 
WHERE News.NewsActive = 1 
ORDER BY TotalComments DESC;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, thank you so much. One last question, how can I print number of total comments of a news? Would "COUNT(*) AS TotalComments" do it?